# Is it possible to use the build in iOS crop tool in my app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

In the photo albums app there's a build in edit -> cropping tool. Is it possible to use that tool in an app instead of writing it on my own?  Is it a part of the framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no built-in crop tool. However, it would not be that hard to write such a tool.

You'd need to create a control that let the user drag around an image in a scroll view, and collect the coordinates.

Then you'd create a graphics context and use the UIImage method drawInRect: to draw the image into a rect that's larger than the graphics context. The result would be to draw a cropped portion of the image into the context. Then you'd extract an image from the graphics context and discard the graphics context.

Answer (score 1):

No that is not part of SDK, but you can easily crop images in iOS.

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image width:(float)w height:(float)h {
    UIImage *croppedImage = image;

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(w, h);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height);
    [image drawInRect:rect];

    croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return croppedImage;
}
```

Comment: That's not the hard part; the hard part (which is doable, just not in the dozen-lines range) is implementing the view that the user would drag around to set the crop rect.

Answer (score 1):

I created a crop tool that might fit your need. It's not based on a scroll view, but rather letting the user choose a frame around their image.

https://github.com/nicholjs/BFCropInterface